# line chart transition not working with svelte and d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svelte

I am trying to make a transition in a line chart using d3 and svelte.

What I want is for the line to be updated and animated to its new position. Right now, data is updated but path is not being animated.

I am quite new to svelte and maybe missing something obvious. Would be super greatful for any help!

I tried to do it with css transition, but animation does not work as well: https://svelte.dev/repl/c6ba8a2c2a83451fb86c105550cc5aa4?version=3.38.2

Here is another attempt:
https://svelte.dev/repl/22b305a7c72647669987a2d95cce6eed?version=3.38.2

Comment: Chances are you'll need to write your own tweening function or find one for svg paths specifically (eg, use one of the d3 extensions that tween paths). Interpolating between a paths with varying numbers of points is not simple (especially when curves are applied). eg, how does one interpolate between `M10 10 L 10 10` and `M 5 5 L 15 5 L 30 30`? Should the first and last points remain the first and last points with a new point in between or should a new point be added to the start or end? Now add curves. Most  interpolators expect the same number of numerical values in start and end strings.